# Taking a query and loading an array with unique values from one of the query fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I have a query whose results contain a "week_of" date stamp.   To work with the results, I need a unique list of the "week_of" dates in a seperate array.

I did what I was wanting like below, I was just wondering if there's an easier/shorter way to do something like this (take a query and then load an array with the unique values in one of the query fields).  Thanks!

```
  @test = []

  @my_query.each do |x|
    if @test.size > 0
      flag = 0
      @test.each do |t|
        if t == x.week_of
          flag = 1
        end
      end
      if flag == 0
        @test << x.week_of
      end
    else
      @test << x.week_of
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@test = []
@my_query.each do |x|
  @test << x.week_of
end
@test.uniq!
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will turn the list of results into a list of unique week_of entries:

```
@my_query.map do |x| x.week_of end.uniq
```

Both `map` and `uniq` are explained in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html.